# How to return nested json in one row using JSON_TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, nested

I am struggling with the following query. I have json and it is splitting the duration and distance elements over two rows. I need them in one and cannot see where to change this.

The following will just work from SQL*Plus etc (Oracle 20.1)

```
select * 
from json_table(
'{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Page St, London SW1P 4BG, UK" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Corbridge Drive, Luton, LU2 9UH, UK" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "88 km",
                  "value" : 87773
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 hours 25 mins",
                  "value" : 4594
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}', 
    '$' COLUMNS
      (
         origin_addresses      varchar2(1000 char) path '$.origin_addresses[*]',
         destination_addresses varchar2(1000 char) path '$.destination_addresses[*]',
         nested path '$.rows.elements.distance[*]' 
         COLUMNS(
            distance_text  varchar2(100) path '$.text',
            distance_value varchar2(100) path '$.value'
                ),
         nested path '$.rows.elements.duration[*]' 
         COLUMNS(
            duration_text varchar2(100) path '$.text',
            duration_value varchar2(100) path '$.value'
                )                  
      )
);
```

Mathguy: I don't have influence over the JSON that Google returns but origin and destinations are arrays it is just this search is from A to Z and not A,B,C to X,Y,Z for example which would return 9 results instead of 1

[See results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snRJ0.png)

Comment: The structure of your input JSON string is wrong. You have a key "elements" with value a JSON array, whose members are not similar to each other. Instead, the value of "elements" should be an object, not an array. Then you wouldn't have to jump through all these hoops.

Comment: For that matter, why are "origin_address" and "destination_address" arrays? Their values should be scalars (single strings). What is the expected output if there are three origin addresses and two destination addresses, all in the same single top-level JSON object?

Comment: Thanks Mathguy. This is a bit of a problems then as I don't have control over the return JSON as it's from Google. Those parameters that are returned can actually be an array of you make a request with multiple origins or destinations and in these examples you'd get o * d as the number of rows back. I'll see I the Google API can help but if we assume they are arrays (containing one element), does this change anything?